# mongodb failed to start on ubuntu 18.04lts

Tags: mongodb

I have tried installing and launching mongo from the official mongo documentation and i can use the mongo shell with the command mongo but i cannot launch the service using mongod the error i get is this

mongod

```
2018-11-29T09:13:30.219-0800 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2018-11-29T09:13:30.229-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4835 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ubuntu
2018-11-29T09:13:30.230-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.4
2018-11-29T09:13:30.230-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f288a3bdf201007f3693c58e140056adf8b04839
2018-11-29T09:13:30.230-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-11-29T09:13:30.230-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-11-29T09:13:30.230-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-11-29T09:13:30.230-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-11-29T09:13:30.230-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-11-29T09:13:30.230-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-11-29T09:13:30.230-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-11-29T09:13:30.230-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-11-29T09:13:30.231-0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2018-11-29T09:13:30.231-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-11-29T09:13:30.231-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear : `SocketException: Address already in use` . You already have another instance (or another program) running on 27017. Find it and kill it. You can use `lsof -i:27017`

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't change anything. i still get the same error the port doesnt close for some reason.

Comment: so do you get any output for `lsof -i:27017` ?

Comment: no i get no output after that command

Comment: what about `netstat -ta | grep 27017`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please start mongodb with sudo. You need to start mongodb using sudo command and than you can use mongo as normal user.

```
> sudo service mongod start

> mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you are installed mongodb instead of mongo-org.
After installing mongodb like sudo apt install mongodb then start the service.
sudo systemctl start mongodb for start the service and by default start when the system boots then use sudo systemctl enable mongodb.